# How to keep a shell open across multiple ajax requests in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, shell

I need to use a shell across multiple ajax requests. Basically this means that the next request should be able to continue with the same shell where the other process left off.

The purpose is to communicate with daemons like FTP to open an FTP connection and log in and in the next request continue with that connection and be able to use it for uploads. But it's not limited to only the FTP daemon (as I know that FTP is supported in PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon the system you want to design but in general, it could be done by maintaining request levels in session or in database, i.e. first check for login, if user is logged in then shell can allow more requests. You may need to define steps of communication for which requests are desired.

Comment: This cannot be done with sessions, because resources cannot be stored as sessions in PHP. "Some types of data can not be serialized thus stored in sessions. It includes resource variables or objects with circular references (i.e. objects which passes a reference to itself to another object)." http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php
I'm not sure what your exact idea is. Can you elaborate, maybe with some examples?